# Missing parameter from url rewritting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

**Hello guys,**

I have a problem with my url rewriting. And I am struggling to find the solution..

Here is part of my rewriting rule :

```
RewriteRule trips/create$ /?page=trips&action=create [L]
RewriteRule trips/(.*)/(.*)$ /?page=trips&group_id=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

When I try to access the url, two scenarii :

```
http://localhost:8080/trips/1265/1/friends
```

The data retrieved from the $_GET

```
array(3) {
  ["page"]=>
  string(5) "trips"
  ["group_id"]=>
  string(6) "1265/1"
  ["id"]=>
  string(7) "friends"
}
```

I should have 4 elements in my array, but only 3. You can see that the key group_id has 2 values (1265 and 1)

How comes thats I don't $_GET 4 parameters but 3 ?

**Thanks you guys**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,

```
RewriteRule trips/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ /?page=trips&group_id=$1&id=$2&tools=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule trips/(.*)/(.*)?$ /?page=trips&group_id=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I have moved the longer rewriting before the short one, it works now !

Comment: You should be as specific as possible when it comes to regex. In your subgroups, if you instead captured just a single path segment (eg. `([^/]+)` instead of `(.*)`) then your original directive would have resulted in a more obvious 404, rather than malformed data ("1265/1") being passed to your script. If a path segment should only contain digits then match only digits. eg. `(\d+)`. You are also missing a start-of-string anchor on the _pattern_, so I could potentially construct malicious links of the form `/any-spam-keywords-trips/1265/1/friends` and still reach the same page.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'll document myself a bit more on the topic !